# Aggregation with nodejs driver - grouping by whether a field is empty

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

The docs are simple as:

```
[
  {'id': '1', 'type': 'a', 'startedAt': '2017-06-11'},
  {'id': '2', 'type': 'b', 'startedAt': ''},
  {'id': '3', 'type': 'b', 'startedAt': '2017-06-11'}
]
```

And the expected aggregated result:

```
[
  {'type': 'a', 'started': true, 'count': 1},
  {'type': 'b', 'started': true, 'count': 1},
  {'type': 'b', 'started': false, 'count': 1}
]
```

How to get above result with mongodb nodejs driver?

I've tried like below, but it didn't work ('started' was always null):

```
db.collection('docs').group(
      {'type': '$type', 'started': {
        $cond: [{$eq: ['$startedAt': '']}, false, true ]
      }}, 
      {}, 
      {'total': 0},
      'function(curr, result) {result.total++}'
    )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use [`.aggregate()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Collection.html#aggregate) here and not [`.group()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Collection.html#group), which is a different function altogether:

```
db.collection('docs').aggregate([
  { "$group": {
    "_id": {
      "type": "$type",
      "started": {
        "$gt": [ "$startedAt", "" ]
      }
    },
    "count": { "$sum": 1 }
  }}
],function(err, results) {
   console.log(results);
})
```

The [`$gt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/gt/) operator returns `true` when the condition is met. In this case any content in a string is "greater than" an empty string.

If the field is actually "not present at all" then we can adapt with [`$ifNull`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/). This gives a default have if the property does not actually exist, or otherwise evaluates to `null`.

```
db.collection('docs').aggregate([
  { "$group": {
    "_id": {
      "type": "$type",
      "started": {
        "$gt": [ { "$ifNull": [ "$startedAt", ""] }, "" ]
      }
    },
    "count": { "$sum": 1 }
  }}
],function(err, results) {
   console.log(results);
})
```

This would produce:

```
{ "_id" : { "type" : "b", "started" : true }, "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : { "type" : "b", "started" : false }, "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : { "type" : "a", "started" : true }, "count" : 1 }
```

You can optionally [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) afterwards to change the fields from being within `_id` in the results, but you really should not since this means an additional pass through results, when you can just as easily access the values anyway.

So just [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?v=example) on the result:

```
console.log(
  results.map(function(r) { 
    return { type: r._id.type, started: r._id.started, count: r.count }
 })
);
```

But with [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/):

```
db.collection('docs').aggregate([
  { "$group": {
    "_id": {
      "type": "$type",
      "started": {
        "$gt": [ { "$ifNull": [ "$startedAt", ""] }, "" ]
      }
    },
    "tcount": { "$sum": 1 }
  }},
  { "$project": {
    "_id": 0,
    "type": "$_id.type",
    "started": "$_id.started",
    "count": "$tcount"
  }}
],function(err, results) {
   console.log(results);
})
```

Resulting in your desired format

```
{ "type" : "b", "started" : true, "count" : 1 }
{ "type" : "b", "started" : false, "count" : 1 }
{ "type" : "a", "started" : true, "count" : 1 }
```

---

For reference, the correct usage with [`.group()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Collection.html#group) would be:

```
  db.collection('docs').group(
    function(doc) {
      return {
        "type": doc.type,
        "started": (
          (doc.hasOwnProperty('startedAt') ? doc.startedAt : "") > ""
        )
      }
    },
    [],
    { "count": 0 },
    function(curr,result) {
      result.count += 1
    },
    function(err,results) {
      console.log(results);
    }
  );
```

Which returns:

```
[
    { "type" : "a", "started" : true, "count" : 1  },
    { "type" : "b", "started" : false, "count" : 1 },
    { "type" : "b", "started" : true,  "count" : 1 }
]
```

But you really should no use that since [`.group()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Collection.html#group) relies on JavaScript evaluation that runs much slower than what you can do with [`.aggregate()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Collection.html#aggregate)

Comment: This answer is comprehensive, let alone it works. I will stick to the .aggregate + .map, and leave $project or .group alone. @neil-lunn, Thanks a ton!